# Why my map is not returning array elements on the page in real time

Tags: javascript, reactjs

When I am trying to add notes to the todo then the elements are pushing in the array, and I can see the elements in console.

But without refreshing the page I am not able to see the elements.

My local storage implementation is also correct

What is wrong here,

```
import "./styles.css";
import { useState, useRef, useEffect } from "react";
export default function App() {
  let array = [];
  let notes = localStorage.getItem("notes");
  if (notes !== null) {
    array = JSON.parse(notes);
  }
  const Add = () => {
    array.push(one.current.value);
    localStorage.setItem("notes", JSON.stringify(array));
    console.log("after adding the value -> ", array);
  };
  const one = useRef(null);
  return (
    <>
      <div className="App">
        <h1>Hello CodeSandbox</h1>
        <div className="align">
          <input ref={one} />
          <br />
          <br />
          <button onClick={Add}>Add</button>
        </div>
        <div className="align">
          {array.map((e, index) => {
            console.log(index, "-> ", e);
            return (
              <div key={index} index={index + 1} name={e}>
                {e}
              </div>
            );
          })}
        </div>
      </div>
    </>
  );
}
```

This is the codesandbox link

https://codesandbox.io/s/silly-neumann-b0foos?file=/src/App.js:0-973

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Nothing here is set to react to changes or trigger re-renders.

`array` should be a state variable with setter as should be your `<input>` value

```js
const [array, setArray] = useState(
  JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("notes")) ?? []
);
const [note, setNote] = useState("");

// Update localStorage when array changes
useEffect(() => {
  localStorage.setItem("notes", JSON.stringify(array));
}, [array]);

const Add = () => {
  setArray((prev) => [...prev, note]); // append note
  setNote(""); // clear the input
};
```

You should also treat your `<input>` as a [controlled component](https://reactjs.org/docs/forms.html#controlled-components)

```html
<input value={note} onChange={(e) => setNote(e.target.value)} />
```

[image: Edit summer-sun-ueukqd]

Comment: I was trying to do exactly the same but I was running into errors. Thanks!!